# Change separator of created array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
var arrEmailID = [];

var emailSpan = $(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');
var _sid ="";
if (emailSpan.length > 0) {
    $(emailSpan).each(function (){

             _sid = $(this).attr('sid');
            _sid = sid.split("|")[2];
             arrEmailID.push(_sid);
        })
```

So I build an array depending of received items, so at the final of the day I receive items separated by commas like:
[image]

is it possible to change that commas for `;`? Regards

Answer (score 3):

That's just how the Chrome console represents the array. Your items are not literally separated by commas.

If you wish to see them separated by semicolons, you'll need to join it into a string.

`console.log("[" + arrEmailID.join(";") + "]");`